# Ехать — повелительное наклонение

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Хотелось бы знать, как образовать форму повелительного наклонения от глагола **ехать**.
Спасибо.

Comment: "Езжай" (в ед. числе) и "езжайте" (в мн. числе).

P.S. Посмотрел ответы и осознал, что я - представитель обыкновенного [русского] народа.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А никак! Правильная форма - поезжай, поезжайте. Т.е. от приставочного глагола. Ехай, едь, езжай - ненормативно. Правда, в разной степени. Некоторые словари допускают  форму "езжай" в разговорной речи.

Comment: Только сейчас обратил внимание. Тут дело не в "приставочных глаголах", а в изрядной путаницие с функциями трех глаголов "ехать", "ездить" и "(по)езжать". Последний исторически являлся личной формой к "ездить", но со временем приобрел частично самостоятельную парадигру спряжений - и даже инфинитив. Все три означают в обще-то одно и то же с небольшими различиями, которые в ряде форм - в т.ч. повелительном наклонении - не прсматриваются. Подобной синонимии язык обычно не терпит - и какие-то формы или просто не могут изначально образроваться, или преходят в разряд ненормативных.

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю.
"Езжай" действительно потихоньку приобретает слабую нормативность. Это объяснимо, "поезжай" - глагол приставочный и ассоциируется с совершенным видом. В то время как исходное "ехать" - глагол несовершенного вида.

~~~~22.08.2012

> А как воспринимается слово "едь"? Очень интересно было бы узнать.

(Nikolja)

Если вводить некоторую градацию грубости ошибок (в порядке: разговорное - просторечное - неправильное - недопустимое или грубо неправильное), то неправильные формы в порядке убывания нормативности можно расположить в следующем порядке: "Езжай" - "Едь" - "Ехай" - "Поехай".
Градация, разумеется, условная, но порядок именно такой.

~~~~

> Правильная форма - поезжай, поезжайте. Т.е. от приставочного глагола.

(Ларf)

Только сейчас обратил внимание. Тут дело не в "приставочных глаголах", а в изрядной путанице с функциями трех глаголов "ехать", "ездить" и "(по)езжать". Последний исторически являлся личной формой к "ездить" (особо - в причастиях), но со временем приобрел частично самостоятельную парадигму спряжений - и даже инфинитив. Все три означают в общем-то одно и то же с небольшими различиями, которые в ряде форм - в т.ч. повелительном наклонении - не просматриваются. Подобной синонимии язык обычно не терпит - и какие-то формы или просто не могут изначально образоваться, или переходят в разряд ненормативных.

Answer (score 2):

От основы глагола ехать форма повелительного наклонения в литературном языке не используется
(встречающиеся в речи формы едь, ехай нелитературны), вместо нее употребляется слово ''поезжай''.

См.также здесь:[Ехать — повелительное наклонение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 2):

И правда, почему всё так? Вопросов, однако, больше, чем ответов.

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК

Форма повелительного наклонения глагола образуется  от основы настоящего времени с помощью суффикса И или нулевого суффикса.

ЕХАТЬ, еду, едешь;      ЕЗДИТЬ, езжу, ездишь;  не езди

ИДТИ, иду, идёшь; иди     ХОДИТЬ, хожу ходишь;  не ходи

ЕЗЖАТЬ  (устар.) часто ездить

ПОПРОБУЕМ ОБРАЗОВАТЬ ПОВЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ НАКЛОНЕНИЕ

Идти -  иду – иди, ехать -  еду – (едь) – не разрешено,  ехать – (ехает) - (ехай) - нет таких форм, не разрешено.
Тогда  (езжать)  - (езжает) – езжай.

ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

Повелительное наклонение глагола "езжай" образовано от инфинитива "езжать", который в современном русском языке относят к просторечной форме, сохранившей значение «многократно ездить», «часто проезжать». Оно закрепилось за этим глаголом в разговорном стиле, хотя вплоть до конца XIX века слово езжать считалось общеупотребительным и часто встречалось в художественной речи. У А. С. Пушкина в «Евгении Онегине» находим: Она езжала по работам, Солила на зиму грибы,Вела расходы, брила лбы,Ходила в баню по субботам…
http://thedifference.ru/kak-pishetsya-pravilno-poezzhaj-ili-ezzhaj/

А откуда взялось «поезжай»? Говорят, что это смягченный вариант от «езжай», но так ли это?  Почему нельзя использовать две формы: езжай и поезжай, они же могут различаться по значению (приставка ПО обычно обозначает начало действия). Вот, к примеру,  ребенок задумчиво крутит педали. Что ему  сказать? Езжай быстрее. Поезжай, наконец, почему остановился?